# Font relative sizing & screen resolution- flash player

Tags: flash, apache-flex, font-size

We are building a flash based product (coded in flash builder) and need to ensure that the font size is readable for all standard screen resolutions- we coded fontsize to be a fraction of screen dimensions... still we find that it looks smaller on low resolution and larger on higher resolution

we dont have this problem with other assets like containers/images etc

Any ideas why this happens? Any thoughts on how we can make it uniform across screen resolutions?

Answer (score 2):

[Flex 4.5](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/introducing-flex45sdk.html) has the latest version of the TLF library (TLF 2.0) directed at handling large amounts of text better and displaying text at different resolutions.

[This article](http://devgirl.org/2011/04/11/flash-builder-4-5-mobile-highlights/) also helps highlight some of the changes coming in 4.5.  Take a look at the sections titled **Handling Resolution** and **CSS Media Queries** and see if it helps.

A quick example from that site:

```
@media (os-platform: "Android") and (application-dpi: 240) {
s|Button {
     fontSize: 10;
}
```